# Finite Idempotent Semirings (Dioids)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

How many finite idempotent semirings (dioids) are there of order n?

And how many have an addition operation that coincides with a maximum operation for some ordering of the elements ?

Even if the exact numbers aren't known, what bounds are there?

As per Todd's comment: underlying additive structure is a commutative monoid, the underlying multiplicative structure is a monoid, and multiplication distributes over addition?

Idempotent means the addition satisfies a+a=a.

Multiplication is not necessarily commutative. (Correspondence principle for idempotent
calculus and some computer applications. G. L. Litvinov and V. P. Maslov)

Also the statement a***0**=**0** has to be stated as it is independent of the others (M. A. Shubin (1992), "Algebraic remarks on idempotent semirings and the kernel theorem in spaces of bounded functions’" in books.google.com/books?&id=ZoxXoYoZuo0C&oi=fnd&pg=PA151)

Dioids are described as plentiful in "An Introduction to Idempotency" Jeremy Gunawardena

They are ennumerated for some special cases in J. H. Conway. Regular Algebra and Finite Machines. Chapman and Hall, 1971, Chapter 12

Comment: Do your semirings have a multiplicative identity? So in other words, do you mean the underlying additive structure is a commutative monoid, the underlying multiplicative structure is a monoid, and multiplication distributes over addition? 


Comment: Yes to all those.

Comment: These idempotent semirings without any further restrictions are described as a vast class by M. A. Shubin (1992), "Algebraic remarks on idempotent semirings and the kernel theorem in spaces of bounded functions’" in books.google.com/books?&id=ZoxXoYoZuo0C&oi=fnd&pg=PA151

Comment: Regarding your second question: Do you mean to ask how many have an addition which doesn't come from a max operation? I ask because I am really only familiar with the semiring one gets by using "max" as the addition and "plus" as the multiplication on the reals. However, if this is your intended question, then the answer may be zero. Also, have you looked at any of Golan's texts on semirings?

Comment: Oops. Getting myself muddled. Yes. Thankyou.

Comment: Well if you have a commutative idempotent operation + then the relation $\leq$ defined by $a\leq b$ iff $a+b=b$ is a partial order. This is why (if I am correctly interpreting what you are asking) I think the answer to your second question is zero.

Comment: The numbers from 0 to n with the relation 0<1<2<...<n form a total order and the max function on this order is a commutative idempotent operation.

Comment: Sorry. Your previous version was asking how many did *not* coincide with a max operation. I am saying that all of them do appear as a max with respect to some ordering.